# Ubuntu server : SSH by default (setup without monitor)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu, openssh

I need to setup a Raspberry Pi 4 without a Monitor,
I want to run a light version without GUI just to run some docker, I though Ubuntu Server was a good idea.

I try to add a SSH file on the microSD like I would with raspbian but that don't seems to work

PS is Pi the default user for Ubuntu Server Raspberry because that might be issue

How can I get SSH working without a monitor ?

Comment: Have you tried Raspbian Buster lite? It's basically Raspbian without the desktop. Things like enabling SSH / wifi credentials work the same as on the desktop version.

Comment: Yes I had it before, just wanted to try Ubuntu server, but guess can go back to it, work just fine alright

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation today

Although it is already 7 months from @Kevin's question this is how I solved it.

Once you have your Ubuntu (20.04 in my case) installation ready in your USB, edit the **user-data** file

[image]

Under the section **## Install additional packages on first boot**,
Uncomment **packages**, and add a new entry for the **openssh-server** package.

For example:

```
## Install additional packages on first boot
packages:
- openssh-server
```

Five minutes (more or less) after my Raspberry Pi 2B boot I was able to connect to my Pi 2 through ssh :)